# Safely closing Esper Statement with time_batch

Tags: java, esper

I have a Esper statement which uses to join two event types. It has a `time_batch`. Statement look like follows.

```
select * from LogEvent1.std:firstunique(transactionId).win:time_batch(1 min) log1
  left outer join
  LogEvent2.std:firstunique(transactionId).win:time_batch(1 min) log2
  on log1.transactionId = log2.transactionId
```

So the events are batched for 1 Minute and then released. My question is how to handle the application shutdown without loosing accumulated but not yet release events.

Is there a way to stop the statement which will fire the accumulated events in the buffer. I tested with `EPStatement.stop()` methods, but it doesn't release the current accumulated events in the batch.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set time for the statement to sometime in the future.

You could also use statement.iterate().

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by manually advancing time.

```
val nextExecutionTime: Long = esperRuntime().getNextScheduledTime
esperProvider.getEPRuntime.sendEvent(new TimerControlEvent(TimerControlEvent.ClockType.CLOCK_EXTERNAL))
esperProvider.getEPRuntime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(nextExecutionTime + 1000))
//Wait till processing finishes
Thread.sleep(1000);
```